# Firebase currentUser is null after app update

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

What I do in my app is on every start I check if Firebase user is valid and authenticated before proceeding to my apps content.

```
firebaseAuth.currentUser?.let {
      val userQuery = usersCollectionRef
           .whereEqualTo(FIRESTORE_USER_FIELD_ID, it.uid)
           .get()
           .await()

      if (userQuery.documents.isNotEmpty()) {
           val userDocument = userQuery.documents.first()
           val user = userDocument.toObject(FirestoreUser::class.java)

           user
      } else {
          null
      }
}
```

For some reason, `firebaseAuth.currentUser` returns `null` whenever my app has a new update on the store - not sure if that's coincidence or not. Am I doing something wrong? Is this expected? How to make sure that currentUser does not return `null` after user has logged in?

P.S. I have AppCheck enabled

Comment: You're supposed to use an auth state listener ([AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)) to get a callback when it's known for sure if the user is signed in or not. currentUser will be initially null before the state is known.  Read the entire section of the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) to understand the issues.

Comment: For an example of an auth state listener on Android, see my article inn the Google Cloud collective: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android

Comment: Maybe this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).